# Caller doesn't get event of End Call from receiver in opentok ios sdk

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, xcode5, opentok

I have an iphone app in which I need to manage video call from caller to receiver and its works perfectly by using Opentok framework. Video call and audio everything working fine. 
But I have a problem with Ending a call from receiver side without picking up the call.

If receiver picked up the call and Then he ends the call then caller receives event of ending a call. But when if receiver doesn't picked up the call from app and directly end the call then caller doesn't get any event and it continuously showed up the calling screen. All delegates and its methods are implemented.

Delegates are `OTSessionDelegate`, `OTSubscriberDelegate`, `OTPublisherDelegate`. And it's all required and optional methods are implemented and working fine.

objects in header file are

```
#import <Opentok/Opentok.h>
@interface myViewController : UIViewController
{
      OTSession* session;
      OTPublisher* publisher;
      OTSubscriber* subscriber;
}
```

And I am calling `doUnpublish` method to end the call. The code is

```
- (void)doUnpublish
{

    [loaderviewView removeFromSuperview];
    [_session unpublish:_publisher];
    [_session disconnect];
    [player stop];
     [self doDisconnect];
 }


- (void)doDisconnect
{
   [callingView setHidden:YES];
   timer invalidate];
    [_session disconnect];
}
```

It is working fine if receiver receive the call and then ends the call. But if he doesn't receive the call and directly ends up then caller doesn't get event that call is ended by receiver.

I does not provide more code because it contains private details code which I have to manage for call information. And it is not a problem and working fine. I just need to know how can i get event in caller side that receiver ended a call without Accepting the call.

My whole app is ready and because of this situation I am paused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi max i need your help. i want to implement video calling using opentok. can u send me the code for that it will helpful to me.

Comment: @User558. How can I send you code? that is a big project not a small code. You can use demo project of opentok sdk to understand the flow. You can ask question when you don't understand or stuck at something.

Comment: I implemented video calling it's  working fine. how to get incoming call to other device?

Comment: @User558 I am working in company, I can't share the whole project. I can help by giving tips and suggestion or small code but can't share the whole code

Comment: We have done through API, we have shared same session ID between both party then connect them by same session and get notifications of event sessionDidConnect and other actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128432/discussion-between-max-and-user558).

Comment: How you managed to notify the receiver when dealer disconnects the call before receiver accepts it?

Comment: @khush, To notify the receiver, when call comes on dealer side, I connect to that session  while ringing, and disconnect or end that session if call declined.

Comment: @Max so didn't it send an event  of  ```subscriberDidConnect``` at the dealer side?

Comment: @khush, No just create masterSession with that session id but do not call doSubscriber or doPublish until accepting the call or do not create subscriber/publisher, and call session disconnect if call declined

Comment: @Max how to stop phone ringing? any specific piece of code?

Comment: @khush If you use callkit than it depends on system mode whether it is in silent mode or ringing etc.. if you are using custom incoming screen than you have control to manage that like do not assign sound... or stop sound playing etc..

Comment: @Max I am using CallKit but the ring never goes off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Receiver clicks on end call your doUnpublish method gets called, which in turns calls session disconnect to disconnect from an opentok session. Session disconnect causes the Caller's delegate connectionDestroyed to get triggered so Caller knows that Receiver has disconnected from the session.

The problem arises when Receiver never picks up the call so he never connects to the OpenTok Session. If he never connects to the session, the Caller's connectionCreated and connectionDestroyed delegates will never get fired.

The way to solve your problem is to set a timer. On the caller's end, start the timer when he calls the Receiver. If connectionCreated delegate is not fired in 1 minute, that means that the Receiver either rejected the call or missed the call.

Comment: is it feasible to set a timer only or can i have to give a message for that to caller?

Comment: After the timer expires, caller should call session.disconnect() so that it leaves the session.
You probably also want to add a timer on the receiver side so that it doesn't keep ringing forever.

Comment: no from receiver side, if user ends call in any way or disconnected than automatically disconnected from receiver side and stop music.

Comment: You would need some type of messaging between the caller and receiver such that when caller/receiver ends call in any way, the other party should get a notification to end the call as well.

Comment: in my case I have pick up call but still getting ringing on other side