# CallKit using with OpenTok

Tags: ios, opentok

I using Opentok with call kit for audio & video calling. Everything is working fine, but I am facing the issue when receiver rejects the call then the caller didn’t get notified that the receiver has rejected the call or if caller end call before picking the call same receiver didn't get notified that call has disconnected the call. If the receiver has been disconnected the call then the caller should get notified instantly. If anyone has the solution for this please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: you can find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309084/caller-doesnt-get-event-of-end-call-from-receiver-in-opentok-ios-sdk[1] here

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @gauravbajaj, I have already checked this thread. But I have to notify the user if the receiver rejected the call. Is there any method where I can notify the caller that the receiver rejected the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notifiy to caller with signal. when receiver end the call then pass signal.

```
Session.sendSignal("type", "message", Connection);
```

At the receiver end To start receiving all signals, call the setSignalListener(Session.SignalListener listener) method of the Session object, passing in an object that implements the Session.SignalListener interface:

```
Session.setSignalListener(this);
```

The onSignalReceived(Session session, String type, String data, Connection connection) method of the SignalListener object is called when a signal is received in the session:

```
protected void onSignalReceived(Session session, String type, String data, Connection connection) {
String myConnectionId = session.getConnection().getConnectionId();
if (connection != null && connection.getConnectionId().equals(myConnectionId)) {
    // Signal received from another client
}
```

}

Comment: Again thanks for your help, but the above code will be used when a call(Session) is connected(created). I make the session only when the user picks the call. If the receiver didn't pick the call then the session is not there, so we can't use the above method. I want to notify the user when a call is rejected by the receiver. A session is not created until the user picks the call. Can you please suggest the scenario for the session creation.

Comment: 1. When user receive any call then create a session and use that session. 2 Call a api on end button and you server side send a push notification to caller device. 3. when caller make a call then continues call a API that check the response form receiver end, and receiver side call an api on end click.

Comment: Yes, I am following the same steps. But sometimes push deliver too late so not able to figure it out. Is it possible to create a session before picking the call? Please suggest me if you have done it. 
Thanks

Comment: I used push notification approach and that worked fine for me. Please see link for session creation. https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/ios/swift/basic-video-chat/#connect

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you found you solution?

Comment: I have managed it through API & push notification. Thanks for showing interest in my problem :)

Comment: Welcome, happy coding